# Failed to obtain cell from data source?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Xcode returned an error saying the table view had failed to obtain a cell from its data source. I am using a search bar to type in a search term and have it appear underneath in a table view.

My first thought was to check that I had set the cell identifier as `cell` correctly and this is correct, but I think something else might be off in this code. If necessary I can add in the rest of my code but I just wanted to see if I am missing something here first.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!
        let selectedItem = searchedItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
        return cell
    }
}
```

Editing to add the full code from the two view controllers. The aim so far is to get the location of user and then to be able to type in a search term, e.g. Target, in the search bar and have search results displayed in the table view.

**First View Controller**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //this variable is for access to the location manager throughout the scope of the controller
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var resultSearchController:UISearchController? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() //this triggers authorization alert - one time only
        locationManager.requestLocation() //triggers an also one time location request

        let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTable
        resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
        resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable


        //configure the search bar and embed within the navigation bar
        let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for places"
        navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar

        //configure the UISearchController appearance
        resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false //ensure search bar is accessible at all times
        resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true //for when search bar is selected
        definesPresentationContext = true

        locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView //passes along a handle of the mapView from the main VC onto the locationSearchTable

    }

}

//extension used for code organization to group delegate methods

extension ViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse { //is user responded with allow
            locationManager.requestLocation() //essentially requesting on the double as first is a permission failure before allow is pressed
        }
    }

    //gets called when location information comes back. You get an array of locations but only interested in first item. Eventually will zoom to this location
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        if let location = locations.first {
            let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05) //span is the zoom level set at arbitrary level for now
            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location.coordinate, span)
            //once you combine coordinate and span into a region you can zoom using setRegion(_:animated:)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("error:: (error)")
    }

}
```

**Second View Controller**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit


class LocationSearchTable : UITableViewController {

    var matchingItems:[MKMapItem] = [] //for stashing search results for easy access
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil //search queries rely on map region for local results. This is ahandle to the map from the previous screen



    //this method converts the placemark to a custom address format like: "4 Melrose Place, Washington DC"

    func parseAddress(selectedItem:MKPlacemark) -> String {
        // put a space between "4" and "Melrose Place"
        let firstSpace = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil && selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) ? " " : ""
        // put a comma between street and city/state
        let comma = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil || selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) && (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil || selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? ", " : ""
        // put a space between "Washington" and "DC"
        let secondSpace = (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil && selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? " " : ""
        let addressLine = String(
            format:"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
            // street number
            selectedItem.subThoroughfare ?? "",
            firstSpace,
            // street name
            selectedItem.thoroughfare ?? "",
            comma,
            // city
            selectedItem.locality ?? "",
            secondSpace,
            // state
            selectedItem.administrativeArea ?? ""
        )
        return addressLine
    }

}

extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let mapView = mapView, let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { //executes the search query
            response, _ in guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: How is the cell defined. Is it in code? have you registered the cell Identifier with the tableview? Have you stepped into this code to see what is happening at each line?

Comment: You must forget to register the cell.

Comment: By register the cell identifier, do you just mean set the cell identifier name in tableview? If so, I did this through the attributes inspector. Or did you mean something else? The cell is a prototype one from storyboard tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. Make sure that you have assigned the right data source.
2. Make sure that you have said in your datasource that its the datasource for UITableView. That it conforms to `UITableViewDataSource` like `YourViewController : UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: The class inherits from UITableViewController and so it said it was redundant to conform to the datasource protocol. Going to post up all of the code for review as I am following a tutorial and it is covering a lot of new ground for me.